# ChartJS Create New chart from variable

Tags: chart.js

This seems pretty straightforward but I'm not understanding why it's not rendering the chart correctly. Is there a way to pass the configuration section below to a new chart as a variable? If I load the chart using the coding below it works perfectly. I've tried putting the configuration section into a variable and then placing that within the configuration section, surrounding it by brackets. When I do there's no errors it's just blank like it's not receiving it correctly.

```
new Chart(myCanvas, {type: 'bar',
data: {
labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
datasets: [{
    label: '# of Votes',
    data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
    backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
    ],
    borderColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
    ],
    borderWidth: 1
}]
},
options: {
    scales: {
        y: {
            beginAtZero: true
        }
    }
}})
```

Comment: Just saying it doesnt work doesnt help, please include the code you are executing where you try to load it as a variable since it works perfectly fine if done correct

Comment: Sure, I updated my question and rephrased it a bit. Basically just trying to figure out how to apply the configuration part of the new chart declaration as a variable. TIA

Answer (score 0):

you must add `document.getElementById("MyChart")` inside Chart() object and you will get something like this

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.6.0/dist/chart.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="MyChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
<script>
new Chart(document.getElementById("MyChart"), {type: 'bar',
data: {
labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
datasets: [{
    label: '# of Votes',
    data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
    backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
    ],
    borderColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
    ],
    borderWidth: 1
}]
},
options: {
    scales: {
        y: {
            beginAtZero: true
        }
    }
}})

;
</script>
```